# ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are some post
s to this subject. But they did not help me. I am using only one data set and this error occurs nevertheless.

`ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

```
wellmixed<-read.table("param_analysis_Spatial.txt",skip=1)
wellmixed[is.na(wellmixed)] <- 0

wellmixed %>%
       group_by(V2) %>%
       arrange(V1) %>%
       mutate(ymin = (V1 + lag(V1))/2
            , ymax = (V1 + lead(V1))/2
            , xmin = V2 - 0.005
            , xmax = V2 + 0.005
            , ymin = ifelse(is.na(ymin), 0, ymin)
            , ymax = ifelse(is.na(ymax), 0.16, ymax)
                   ) %>%

  +     ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin
                 , xmax = xmax
                 , ymin = ymin
                 , ymax = ymax
                 , fill = V7)) +
       geom_rect(data=wellmixed)
```

is it because of the %>%?

Comment: Why is there a `+` before `ggplot`?

Answer (score 0):

You get `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval` message, when the first argument in ggplot() is not data.frame.

If the first argument in ggplot() is your aesthetics, then you need to write:

```
   ggplot(mapping = aes(...your aesthetics...) )
```